# Segmentation Fault after calling method exists()

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

I'm having trouble manipulating a doubly linked list. I'm pretty sure I have my addNode(), getCount(), printList(), and getNode() working fine, but when executing, I get to right around my exists() and deleteNode() methods and I get a segmentation fault. exists() checks to see if a specific node exists, and deleteNode() passes in an id, and if the id matches a node id, it deletes that node. I don't know which method is messing up. Here are both of them. This is also my first post so if it's confusing and not thorough I apologize in advance.

```
bool LinkedList::deleteNode(int id){

    bool didDelete = false;
    bool hasResult = false;
    Node *position;
    position = head;

    while(position!=NULL && !hasResult){

        if(id == position->data.id){
            hasResult = true;
        } else {
            std::cout << "position->next" << std::endl;
            position = position->next;
        }

    }

    // Deletes head node
    if (position->prev == NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = NULL;
        delete (position);
        didDelete = true;
    }

        // Deletes middle node
    else if (position->next != NULL) {
        position->prev->next = position->next;
        position->next->prev = position->prev;
        position->next = NULL;
        position->prev = NULL;
        delete(position);
        didDelete = true;
    }

        // Deletes the tail node
//            else if(position->next == NULL){
    else{
        position->prev->next = NULL;
        position->prev = NULL;
        delete(position);
        didDelete = true;
    }

    return didDelete;

} // End of deleteNode



bool LinkedList::exists(int id){

    Node *position;
    position = head;
    bool gotNode = false;

    while (position != NULL && !gotNode) {

        if(id == position->data.id){
            gotNode = true;
        } else{
            position = position->next;
        }

    }

    return gotNode;

} // End of exists
```

Comment: What happens when *position* is NULL after the end of the first while-loop in deleteNode()?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think it just returns false.

Comment: What will actually happen is the line `if (position->prev == NULL)` will execute, and since `position` is NULL, you've dereferenced a NULL pointer and invoked Undefined Behavior, and thus you'll have a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Woah wait a minute, that actually executes if it's in the condition? That explains so much. I don't how else to ask that condition though, unless I put like `if (position!=NULL)` but then by that point wouldn't it just be another segmentation fault?

Comment: @ProgrammingSensei Merely testing whether a pointer is NULL or not is perfectly safe and well-defined behavior.  Dereferencing a NULL pointer to access data is not safe. That being said, your `deleteNode()` is needlessly complex and verbose, it can be greatly simplified (so can `exists()`, for that matter). In any case, after the 1st loop in `deleteNode()` is done, you should check `hasResult` and exit immediately if it is `false`, before handling `position` any further.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `exists()` is fine, though it can be simplified a little:

```cpp
bool LinkedList::exists(int id){
    for(Node *position = head; position; position = position->next) {
        if (id == position->data.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your `deleteNode()` is broken, though.  If the specified `id` is not found by the `while` loop, `position` will end up `NULL`, and the subsequent access to `position->prev` will invoke *undefined behavior*.

It is also needlessly verbose, it can be greatly simplified:

```cpp
bool LinkedList::deleteNode(int id){
    for(Node *position = head; position; position = position->next){
        if (id == position->data.id){
            if (position->next) position->next->prev = position->prev;
            if (position->prev) position->prev->next = position->next;
            if (position == head) head = head->next;
            /* uncomment this if you ever add such a field...
            if (position == tail) tail = tail->prev;
            */
            delete position;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! I never though to increment to the next node using a for loop. Might’ve been dumb on my end . Thank you so much!